# Как поделиться одновременно и линком и фото в FaceBook ( link and image )

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Приветствую ! Как поделиться одновременно и линком и фото в FaceBook ( link and image ). Ну или поставить линк под фото, чтоб при нажатии переходил по указанной ссылке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правда это не является ответом на мой вопрос, но если у Вас имеется ссылка на картинку то можно сделать так ( Но вопрос был когда не имеется ссылка ):

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentDescription("Description")
            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://...."))
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://....").build();
    ShareApi.share(linkContent, null);
```